# absolute positioned anchor tag (with no text) not clickable in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, css-position

I have two anchors positioned absolute on top of an image, the links are clickable in other browsers (Chrome, FF, Safari) but not in IE (tested in 8 & 9 so far)

The strange thing is if I give the links a `background-color` they are clickable, however if the `background-color` is set to `transparent` (*which is what I want*) they are no longer clickable, I've also tried setting `zoom:1` but no luck.  I guess the `hasLayout` bit in IE went away with IE 8/9 so guessing `zoom` doesn't matter now for this kind of issue.

Any ideas to make these links show up in IE 8/9 with a transparent bg?

Here's the fiddle I've been working with: [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/8Uew6/)

I have the following HTML layout:

```
<div id="content">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/724x300" width="724" height="300" alt="woot" />

    <div id="countdown"></div>

    <a id="link1" href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" title="link1"></a>
    <a id="link2" href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" title="link2"></a>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
body {text-align:center;}
#content {position:relative; width:724px; height:300px; margin:0 auto;}

#countdown {position:absolute; width:650px; height:110px; top:100px; left:30px; background-color:blue;}

#link1 {position:absolute; width:520px; height:35px; bottom:20px; left:0;}
#link2 {position:absolute; width:200px; height:35px; bottom:20px; right:0;}
```

Comment: Your links are invisible unless you are searching for them. Are they not going to have any text in them or something?

Comment: I have run into this problem before too, try using @Michael's solution. That was the only way I was able to accomplish/get around it.

Comment: @tw16 the links will be on top of clickable looking content in the image they're on top of, no text in the links themselves (basically an image map)

Comment: you can encode that to css base64 like here: http://proger.i-forge.net/The_smallest_transparent_pixel/eBQ

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I have had this exact problem before and it has always annoyed the hell out of me. I'm never sure why it happens, but I always create a 1px by 1px transparent PNG (or GIF) and use that in your background declaration like so:

```
a { background: url("/path/to/image.png") 0 0 repeat; }
```

Hope this helps.

PS - Don't specify any actual background colour with this. Just use the example above and it should work.

In addition to this, try and set your anchor tags to display as block and perhaps also insert a non-breaking space in them (since they are empty at the moment and that might be tripping IE up):

```
a { display: block; background: url("/path/to/image.png") 0 0 repeat; }

<a href="#">&nbsp;</a>
```

Comment: I would avoid putting in the extra server call to get the image, since each server call has a big impact on page response time (and also on server load!)

Comment: 1x1 image is a good idea, was kinda hoping for a simpler css solution, the 1x1 seems 90s style web design :)  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: The aggravating thing about the 1x1 image solution (and other "90s style web design" techniques, thanks for making me laugh :)) is that they are really... reliable.  As in, they're obnoxious to implement but they Just Work, and usually in all browsers.  There's no shame in doing this, and unless you're dealing with a very large amount of traffic the extra request won't hurt you.

Comment: Plus if it does hurt you, just add the background dynamically via jQuery for IE or something.  Or use conditional comments.  Or redirect IE users to firefox.com.  Any of these options are great.

Comment: @Michael the `display:block` and `&nbsp;` is not effective, but the bkgd 1x1 is, thx

Comment: THanks, the invisible background image helped me. +1.

Comment: I'd like to clear up a misunderstanding here. All commonly used browsers cache images, so only impact on page load time is time taken to fetch a 1px image once. After that, no impact unless user empties browser cache.

Comment: Worked, but I really don't understand the logic behind it. Does anybody know why this makes a anchor block element clickable even with a &nbsp; inside of it in IE? +1 for the fix.

Comment: @Foxinni No idea...just one of those weird MS bugs. You know how it is! :)

Comment: If you don't want to use an image you can use a base64 encoded string. This works in both IE7 and IE8.

background: url("data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7") 0 0 repeat;

Comment: Something to note about this fix: in iOS, the device gives the `&nbsp;` a property of `color: rgb(0,0,255);`. To fix this, you need to add a `color: transparent;` to every instance of the absolutely positioned link (surprisingly, a global style doesn't work).

Comment: Grab that transparent 1px image from http://www.1x1px.me/
And use http://www.paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/ to only show it on IE8

Comment: @Eddie that was magic brah, I just used that snippet on an almost unrelated IE7 problem and it just worked. Are you from the future?

Answer (score 53):

You can do it using the mentioned `background-image` trick. When you do not want to use a transparent image for this, just use an unknown scheme or `about:blank` in the image URL.

```
a { background-image: url("iehack:///"); }
```

or

```
a { background-image: url("about:blank"); }
```

This works at least in IE 8 + 9 (the only IEs I tested) and in current versions of Firefox and Chrome. It is still valid CSS and causes no additional traffic. The first "hack" may give a JS error in Chrome (and maybe others) when using jquery. The latter only (but surely) gives a MIME-Type warning in Chrome due to the wrong MIME-Type of the `about:blank` document.

Comment: I really favour this solution, because it does not generate any traffic and if it is about browser compatibility and complex projects you will always have to bear with a few warnings in the console. Thank you very much!

Comment: Little longer, but still no traffic, base 64 encoded transparent gif: `background-image: url('data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAPAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==')` ...completely valid.

Comment: @morewry I really think you should post it as an answer. ;-)

Comment: @Kos Wow, 21 votes. Guess I should.  And now I have, plus the solution I used most recently which I don't think has been posted here yet.

Comment: Hack to make it work only on IE6-8: background-image: url("about:blank")\9;

Answer (score 25):

Transplanted from a comment I posted some time ago.

Little longer, but still no traffic, base 64 encoded transparent gif:

```
background-image: url('data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAPAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICR‌​AEAOw==')
```

This has its own pros/cons, but can be useful.  Also:

```
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0)
```

I've used this one more recently

Comment: I like "background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0)" -- it's the most straightforward and the least hacky!

Answer (score 10):

@tw16's comment mentioning `invisible` got me thinking about `opacity`.

Combining IE's `filter:alpha(opacity=0)` with `background-color:#fff` (or any color) appears to be a good solution for this.  Tested and works in IE 7-9 (6 isn't applying the opacity filter for some reason but I'm not required to support 6 so this will work)

The 1x1 image solution is globally effect so I'm going to give the check to him.

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: The only pitfall with this is that you will run into issues with other browsers not making the background opaque. To avoid I just added "opacity: 0;" in addition to what you did, so that it worked across the board. IE9 used "opacity", as well as chrome and firefox, and IE7/8 used "filter".

*Edit*: I liked this answer because it avoids and extra call to the server. While it doesn't mean much to my servers performance, it might speed things up on the client site if they have a slow connection to the internet.

Comment: @CrowderSoup For my situation, I didn't have any issue with other browsers (FF, Chrome, Safari) because the css in my question worked on those, the only issue was in IE, and thus I only used `filter:alpha(...)`.  Ya, I agree about one less roundtrip to the server :)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. My working solution was to add a border to the appropriate anchor. Like the following example. One advantage is, you need no extra image.

```
a { border-right: 1px solid transparent }
```

Answer (score 2):

IE has a nasty habit of not making links work as expected when they don't have any content. To fix this, give each link a `&nbsp;` for content.

Another thing to try is to set `display: block;` on the links to make IE flow them as block-level elements rather than as in-line elements. This can also help is you need the links to be empty.

Comment: `&nbsp;` and `display:block` only gives a very tiny clickable part (for the space), the width/height is still ignored as far as clickable area