# z-index in IE not working

Tags: internet-explorer, z-index

i have a simple example here: http://jsfiddle.net/V97TF/1/ . Basically i need to absolutely position links over an image but for some reason z-index isnt working in any IE :( can please somebody help?

Thanks in advance!

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <style>
        #map {
            float:left;
            position:relative;
        }
        #map img {
            position:relative;
            z-index:9;
        }
        #map .links {
            position:absolute;
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            z-index:10;
            top:0;
            left:0;
        }
        #map .links li {
            width:60px;
            height:25px;
            position:absolute;
        }
        #map .links a {
            display:block;
            height:100%;
            width:100%;
        }
        .karlovy-vary { left:41px; top:87px; }
        .plzen { left:60px; top:143px; }
        .usti-nad-labem { left:110px; top:42px; }
        .ceske-budejovice { left:130px; top:226px; }
        .liberec { left:193px; top:34px; }
        .hradec-kralove { left:243px; top:88px; }
        .pardubice { left:244px; top:132px; }
        .jihlava { left:241px; top:183px; }
        .brno { left:314px; top:210px; }
        .olomouc { left:353px; top:156px; }
        .zlin { left:397px; top:204px; }
        .ostrava { left:400px; top:134px; }
       </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map">
       <img src="http://placekitten.com/501/291">
       <ul class="links map1">
            <li class="karlovy-vary"><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li class="plzen"><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li class="usti-nad-labem"><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li class="ceske-budejovice"><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li class="liberec"><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li class="hradec-kralove"><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li class="pardubice"><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li class="jihlava"><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li class="brno"><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li class="olomouc"><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li class="zlin"><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li class="ostrava"><a href="#"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>   
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working in Internet Explorer 8 with a `background-image` hack (see the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6914822/237244)). The transparent background images didn't seem to work in this particular case. I liked [mdmullinax's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6915405/237244):

```
background-color: #fff;
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
```

But if you need the content of the anchors to be visible, you can use one of [Dio F's solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10557354/237244):

```
background-image: url("about:blank");
```

But be aware that if you use this solution, Dio F said that it gives a MIME-Type warning in Chrome due to the wrong MIME-Type of the `about:blank` document.

I should also say that putting a border on both `#map .links li` and `#map .links a` reveals that the link is not in the exact same position as the list item, at least in Internet Explorer 8. This can be fixed by adding `position: absolute;` to `#map .links a`.