# Hidden clickable link doesn't work without background color in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have this link:

```
<a href="/" style="position: absolute; left: 40px; top: 50px; height: 60px; width: 120px;"> </a>
```

Which works fine in most browsers, except for IE. I tested it in IE8.

When I add a background color, it does work however. But this is not possible on my design. How do I fix this link to be clickable?

```
<a href="/" style="background-color: red; position: absolute; left: 40px; top: 50px; height: 60px; width: 120px;"> </a>
```

edit: I also tested with transparant background, doesn't work either.

Comment: not a good suggestion, once try `background-color: transparent` :)

Comment: just edited my question, doesn't work either

Comment: How are you hiding the link?

Comment: @RenePot try background: none. transparent is by default. (my mistake)

Comment: possible dublicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914822/absolute-positioned-anchor-tag-with-no-text-not-clickable-in-ie

Comment: It makes me confused, your link, as it is, is clickable in an genuine IE8 .? What kind of IE8 are you using ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to avoid your mouse to click through your link, you understood you needed a background-color since there's no content at all.
`background:rgba(0,0,0,0.01);` just does fine, it has a background and still you don't see it.

In fact your link is like it doesn't exist, no text, no title , no nothing but CSS.
 Easter egg :) ?

Unless you have really good reason, it is not a good practice to have such an inconsistant link .

**Actually, In a real IE8 (win XP) your empty link is clikable !**
http://liveweave.com/XvhkJ6 made and tested from a genuine  IE8. :)

Comment: oups, let me start an IE8 to check it takes rgba .. all the sudden i have a doubt.

Comment: right, not rgba avalaible. :) but link is clikable just like this.

Answer (score 0):

Add a transparent gif on a background. It is a known bug in IE.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `background-color: none`

Comment: -1: `none` is not a valid value for `background-color`. `inherit` and `transparent` are.

Comment: sorry, i saw the first comment on this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739665/is-background-colornone-valid-css