# IE10 - Link not clickable on transformed div

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, internet-explorer-10, css-transforms

I am having issues with divs being click-able in IE 10. They have CSS3 transitions and transforms on them. They animate correctly, but the links are not click-able. This works properly in IE 11, FF and Chrome. The anchor will also not work in IE 9 and below, but neither will the CSS transitions. I am at a loss for the reason as to why this is not working in IE 10.

I will not post my CSS here as it is fairly long. I have added a fiddle for viewing full css.

html:

```
<div class="grid">
    <figure class="effect-bubba columns large-4">
        <img alt="" src="http://www.blackduckmn.com/_images/home/blackduck-minnesota-apple.JPG" />
        <figcaption>
             <h2>Lodging &amp; Dining</h2>

             <p>Whatever you're looking for, Blackduck has a variety of lodging and dining options available!</p> <a href="/visit/lodging-and-dining">View more</a>

        </figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/phorden/oysn4rgv/

live page: http://www.blackduckmn.com/

Comment: Not sure it is related to the transform. It is not clickable in IE9 either...and the transforms don't work in IE9.

Comment: @Dismissile Yea, I know the transforms don't work in IE9 or below. I am looking for a solution to IE 10 only if possible.

Comment: Yeah I get that. What I'm saying is that this may not have anything to do with the transform and that the CSS for the anchor itself might be wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in IE where the anchor element requires a background in order for it to fill the space and ultimately be clickable. Try adding a fake background to your rules for the anchor tag.

```
.grid figure a {
    z-index: 1000;
    text-indent: 200%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
    display: block;
    z-index: 100000;

   background: url("data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBR‌​AA7") 0 0 repeat;
}
```

Take a look at the highest rated comment below the answer to the following question:
[absolute positioned anchor tag (with no text) not clickable in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914822/absolute-positioned-anchor-tag-with-no-text-not-clickable-in-ie)

Comment: Thanks so much for the fix, I don't think I would have tracked down this bug on my own.