# Internet Explorer image overlaying link

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

On the following page I have a link and an image, the image is overlaying the link in internet explorer meaning that you can't click it, but in firefox it works as expected.

http://www.hughgrice.com/test/

Why is internet explorer behaving different and how can I fix this?

Sorry for not including the code or a JSFiddle, the code that has ben generated is a bit of a mess and difficult to extract.

Comment: If you force IE to work in standards mode, does it work as expected? (IE dev tools -> force mode). I haven't looked into your code in detail, but I get the feeling that 40 validation errors are making IE go into Quirks mode where all sorts of kooky stuff can happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this post would help?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1664014/1234190

It's about how absolutely positioned <a> tags are only clickable on rendered contents in IE9.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting z-index css property for both link and image?
sort like this:

```
mydiv #link, mydiv2 #image{
   position:relative;
}
mydiv #link{
   z-index:2;
}
mydiv2 #image{
   z-index:1;
}
```

Comment: Hi Mat, thanks for the response, we tried zindex but it still seems to overlay in IE, any other ideas?